# Creating GraphQl schema and resolver for given GraphQl query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, schema, graphql-js

I want to create a GraphQl schema and resolver function for the below GraphQL query

```
query ($DateFilter: Date!, $oType: String, $voyStat: VoyageVoyageStatusCodeEnum)  {
    imos {
      voyageList (query: {
                    limit: 1
                    where:
                    {
                        or : [
                            {lastUpdateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}},
                            {completeDateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}}
                            ]
                        and : [
                            {oprType: {is : $oType }},
                            {voyageStatusCode: {isNot : $voyStat }}
                            ]
                    }
                })  {
          vesselCode
          lastUpdateGmt
          voyageNo
          voyageStatus
          tradeAreaName
          oprType
          completeDateGmt
          commenceDateGmt
          vessel {
              vesselType
              isActive
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the schema I have written so far

```
#graphql
  scalar Date

  type AristowVessel {
    vesselType: String,
    isActive: Boolean
  }

  type VoyageAristow {
    vesselCode: String
    lastUpdateGmt: String
    voyageNo: Int
    voyageStatus: String
    oprType: String
    tradeAreaName: String
    commenceDateGmt: Date
    completeDateGmt: Date
    vessel: AristowVessel
  }

  type VoyageAristowList {
    voyageList: [VoyageAristow]
  }
  
  type Query {
    imos: VoyageAristowList
  }
```

Below is the resolver for the above schema

```
const voyageAristowController = {
    Query: {
      imos: async () => {
        try {
            const voyageData: any = await voyageAristowService.getVoyageData();
            console.log("Voyage Data Response = ",voyageData);
            let vdata:any = [];
            for(let row of voyageData) {
              vdata.push({
                vesselCode: row.vslCode,
                lastUpdateGmt: row.last_update,
                voyageNo: row.voyNum,
                voyageStatus: row.vtype,
                tradeAreaName: row.lob,
                oprType: row.oprType,
                commenceDateGmt: row.commenceGmt,
                completeDateGmt: row.completeGmt,
                vessel: {
                  vesselType: "J32",
                  isActive: true
                }
              });
            }
            return { voyageList: vdata };
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(`Error:  - : ${err}`);
        }
    }
    }
};
```

And this is creating the below query

```
query {
  imos {
    voyageList {
      vesselCode
      lastUpdateGmt
      tradeAreaName
      voyageNo
      voyageStatus
      oprType
      completeDateGmt
      commenceDateGmt
      vessel {
        vesselType
        isActive
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to write the remaining variable and filter part of the given query in my schema and resolver respectively? And how to get the query values in my imos resolver function?

The remaining part is

```
query: {
    limit: 1
    where:
    {
        or : [
            {lastUpdateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}},
            {completeDateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}}
            ]
        and : [
            {oprType: {is : $oType }},
            {voyageStatusCode: {isNot : $voyStat }}
            ]
    }
  }
```

and

```
query ($DateFilter: Date!, $oType: String, $voyStat: VoyageVoyageStatusCodeEnum)
```

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL Queries and mutations have parameters, types don't. Your `VoyageAristowList` type is also redundant. With that in mind you need to specify the parameters of your `imos` query.

```
#graphql
  scalar Date

  type AristowVessel {
    vesselType: String,
    isActive: Boolean
  }

  type VoyageAristow {
    vesselCode: String
    lastUpdateGmt: String
    voyageNo: Int
    voyageStatus: String
    oprType: String
    tradeAreaName: String
    commenceDateGmt: Date
    completeDateGmt: Date
    vessel: AristowVessel
  }

  type Query {
    imos(DateFilter: Date!, oType: String, voyStat: VoyageVoyageStatusCodeEnum ): [VoyageAristow]
  }
```

Then your resolver becomes:

```
const voyageAristowController = {
  Query: {
    imos: async (_,{ dateFilter, oType, voyStat }) => {
    // run your query based on the parameters and return the results
    // note that using .map() to rename all your fields is
    // preferred over .push()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @MichelFloyd. But how can I write the following part in my schema `query: {
    limit: 1
    where:
    {
        or : [
            {lastUpdateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}},
            {completeDateGmt: {isAfter : $DateFilter}}
            ]
        and : [
            {oprType: {is : $oType }},
            {voyageStatusCode: {isNot : $voyStat }}
            ]
    }
  }`

And this is graphql filter?

Comment: Ironically GraphQL is *not* a query language. It does not include filters and sorting capabilities out of the box. You'll have to add an input type that you can use to define the kind of logic you want. OR - you can just write a query with the filters and sorting you want and use it directly (way easier).